# MongoDb nested Indexing for nullable object

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Q: How to create indexing in mongoDB for field "a" where x can also be null, but if there is any "x.a" it will be unique. Is it possible to create such indexing.

**NOTE**: there can be multiple entries with x:null

**collectionName: testing**

```
   {
    "x" : [
           {"a":"Name1","b":"dummy1"}
          ]
   }
```

```
   {
    "x" : [
           {"a":"Name2","b":"dummy2"}
          ]
   }
```

```
  {
    "x":null
  }
```

```
  {
    "x":null
  }
```

Comment: You can look at the [Partial Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/index-partial/index.html). Also, note that index on an _array field_ is called as _Multikey Index_. There are some rules about [Uniqueness in Multikey Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/index-multikey/index.html#unique-multikey-index).

Answer (score 0):

will this works?

```
db.testing.createIndex({"x.a":1})
```